IRS with early termination provision
I have an IRS with an early termination clause (Bermuda style). Do I value it as always or does it have any impact on the value?

Mandatory breaks are quite common on IRS. They are primarily used by corporations without CSAs' to allow that counterparty to gain access to long dated swaps facing banks without high XVA add-on charges. The reason being that the swap is guaranteed to exist only for a certain amount of time hence it typically lowers the calculation of CVA/FVA charges.
From the IRS perspective they are valued as normal, and hedged as normal. Usually a note is placed on these swap to use a market method of termination ahead of the mandatory break so as to not rely on the legal method of termination method specified in the legal docs, which can cause uncertainty for both counterparties.
If the swap is to be rolled this is usually the cheapest methods, becuase it involves terminating the old swap and replacing with a new swap with some new mandatory break clause.
EDIT
If by Bermudan, you mean that the swaps have some embedded optionality (relative to a strike) associated with them then that optionality is a completely different aspect of pricing and these swaps will not be priced the same as a normal swap without the optionality.
